# How to select which where clause to use based off a variable in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to condense my code in order to select which where clause the user would like to use based off a c# variable.

I have tried using parameters and some other ideas I saw online, but could not get it to work.

```
if (btnUseDateRange.Text == "Disabled")
{
 var queryTestedControls =
 (from t in dbContext.UUT_RESULT
 where t.PART_NAME.Contains(ControlSelected)
 && t.UUT_SERIAL_NUMBER.CompareTo(BarcodeStart) >= 0
 && t.UUT_SERIAL_NUMBER.CompareTo(BarcodeEnd) <= 0
 select t.UUT_SERIAL_NUMBER).Count();

 var queryPassedControls =
 (from t in dbContext.UUT_RESULT
 where t.PART_NAME.Contains(ControlSelected)
 && t.UUT_SERIAL_NUMBER.CompareTo(BarcodeStart) >= 0
 && t.UUT_SERIAL_NUMBER.CompareTo(BarcodeEnd) <= 0
 && t.UUT_STATUS == "Passed"
 select t.UUT_SERIAL_NUMBER).Count();

 lblTested.Text = queryTestedControls.ToString();
 lblPassed.Text = queryPassedControls.ToString();
}
else if (btnUseDateRange.Text == "Enabled")
{
 var queryTestedControls =
 (from t in dbContext.UUT_RESULT
 where t.PART_NAME.Contains(ControlSelected)
 && t.START_DATE_TIME >= DateStart
 && t.START_DATE_TIME <= DateEnd
 select t.UUT_SERIAL_NUMBER).Count();

 var queryPassedControls =
 (from t in dbContext.UUT_RESULT
 where t.PART_NAME.Contains(ControlSelected)
 && t.START_DATE_TIME >= DateStart
 && t.START_DATE_TIME <= DateEnd
 && t.UUT_STATUS == "Passed"
 select t.UUT_SERIAL_NUMBER).Count();

 lblTested.Text = queryTestedControls.ToString();
 lblPassed.Text = queryPassedControls.ToString();
}
```

My code will be very long, because I am doing a count for Passed, Failed, Aborted, and Other. Is there a way to condense the query? Based off the button in the if statement, the user is selecting to either query with a barcode range or a datetime range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat shorter

```
var queryTestedControls = from t in dbContext.UUT_RESULT
                          where t.PART_NAME.Contains(ControlSelected)
                          select t;
var queryPassedControls = from t in dbContext.UUT_RESULT
                          where t.PART_NAME.Contains(ControlSelected)
                          select t;                                 

if (btnUseDateRange.Text == "Disabled")
{
    lblTested.Text = queryTestedControls.Where(t => t.UUT_SERIAL_NUMBER.CompareTo(BarcodeStart) >= 0 &&
                                t.UUT_SERIAL_NUMBER.CompareTo(BarcodeEnd) <= 0).Count().ToString();

    lblPassed.Text = queryPassedControls.Where(t => t.UUT_SERIAL_NUMBER.CompareTo(BarcodeStart) >= 0 &&
                                t.UUT_SERIAL_NUMBER.CompareTo(BarcodeEnd) <= 0 &&
                                t.UUT_STATUS == "Passed").Count().ToString();
}
else if (btnUseDateRange.Text == "Enabled")
{
    lblTested.Text = queryTestedControls.Where(t => t.START_DATE_TIME >= DateStart &&
                                t.START_DATE_TIME <= DateEnd).Count().ToString();

    lblPassed.Text = queryPassedControls.Where(t => t.START_DATE_TIME >= DateStart && 
                                t.START_DATE_TIME <= DateEnd && 
                                t.UUT_STATUS == "Passed").Count().ToString();
}
```